# Speed up SQL query using "in" clause

Tags: sql-server

I have been running the following query for 5 minutes, then it timed out as I was typing this.

1. Why did it time out, when I've run plenty of queries longer then 5 minutes before? The error message was "A transport-level error has occurred when receiving results from the server. (provider: TCP Provider, error: 0 - The semaphore timeout period has expired.)"
2. Can I speed this up?  There are about 25,000 records in the subquery (the "in (...)" part).

My code:

```
SELECT
    COUNT(*) 
FROM
    myTable 
WHERE
    AccountID NOT IN (SELECT
                          RIGHT('000000000' + CAST(Col1 AS VARCHAR(9)), 9) 
                      FROM
                          #A) -- Returns records in myTable that no longer exist
```

Comment: You *could* try to `LEFT OUTER JOIN` `mytable` to `#A` `ON myTable.AccountID = RIGHT('000000000' + CAST(Col1 AS VARCHAR(9)), 9) ` And then do a `WHERE #A.Col1 IS NULL` to get the same effect. Can't guarantee it's going to be faster, but `NOT IN()` *can* be a hog.

Comment: Ugh...the first edit to this question removed part of the OPs question by removing one of their queries.

Comment: Thanks, I will try this. I also tried using "NOT EXISTS", but without returning any data, so it seemed to change the result set.

Comment: ...yeah, the editor suggesting changes, and myself, were both editing at the same time and some of it got lost.

Comment: JNevill; that was indeed MUCH faster, thank you. I'm still not quite getting the result set I expect but I'm now looking into other possible reasons for that.

Comment: Instead of using a function like that, couldn't you persist that computed value in a new column on the #A table, throw an index on it, and then do the join, NOT IN, or EXISTS test?

Comment: The better question you should consider is why 2 columns that represent the same value use different datatypes. Is col1 an int? Are you setting yourself (or more likely, someone else) up for failure when a value > 999999999 is encountered? If your response is similar to "will never happen" then there should be a constraint on that column to prevent it (and some documentation why).